# Public-of-chain using proof-of-authority, where authority is defined as the amount of work on your public key

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, proof-of-work

I'm wondering if there would be benefits to create a public blockchain based on the same algorithms used for private, proof-of-authority blockchain, except replacing the concept of authority by the amount of work you did on your public key. That way, you could have the same efficiency of voting-based private blockchains, but in a public one.